# component keeps coming back undefined even tho server prints values

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

Server
The server prints the groups

I am Trying to retrieve all groups from my Mongodb database but the value keeps returning as undefined.
I am creating a react app but i might be getting confused with Aync and how to use the promise

```
router.get('/groups', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const groups = await Group.find().sort({ date: -1 });
        res.json(groups);
        console.log(groups);

    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        res.status(500).send('Server Error');
    }
});
```

Actions

i cant also see the groups being printed here

```
export const getAllGroups = () => async (dispatch) => {
  axios
    .get("/api/group/groups")
    .then(res =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_GROUPS,
        payload: res.payload.data
      })
    )
    .catch(err =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_GROUPS,
        payload: null
      })
   );

};
```

Component
this is where i keep getting the undefined when i try to use groups.

```
class GroupList extends Component {
   
    componentDidMount() => {
       
        const {groups} = await this.props.getAllGroups();
        this.props.getAllGroups(groups)
    }



    // Delete account
    onDeleteClick = id => {
        const { groups } = this.props;
        const groupData = {
            id: id,
            groups: groups
        };
        this.props.deleteGroup(groupData);
    };


    render() {
        const { user, groups } = this.props;
      
                 let groupItems = groups.map(group => (
                     <li key={group._id} style={{ marginTop: "1rem" }}>
                        <button
                            style={{ marginRight: "1rem" }}
                             onClick={this.onDeleteClick.bind(this, group._id)}
                             className="btn btn-small btn-floating waves-effect waves-light hoverable red accent-3"
                        >
                             <i className="material-icons">delete</i>
                         </button>
                         <b>{group.name}</b>
                     </li>
                ));
        
        return (
            <div>
                <Link to="/" className="btn-flat waves-effect">
                    <i className="material-icons left">keyboard_backspace</i> Back to
                    home
                </Link>
                { { <ul>{groupItems}</ul> } }
            </div>
        )

    }

}

GroupList.propTypes = {
    logoutUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    getAllGroups: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    // addAccount: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    deleteGroup: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    groups: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    // plaid: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    user: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    groups: state.groups
});

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    { getAllGroups, deleteGroup }
)(GroupList);
```

Comment: In your server you have your router get "/groups", but your action tries to access "/api/group/groups". Is there more to your routing server-side, which you haven't shown us?

Comment: Yes i have and app.use('api/group') method in my server i didnt mention. It hits the server, i can see the values being printed. the issue is displaing it on the component. it keeps saying undefined. @Geshode